# Make a call immediately from my native React application

Tags: javascript, react-native, tsx

I'm more or less new to react native; I am working on an application which must manage financial transactions (agent transfer, payment of services, etc.). The objective of the application is to be able to execute a USSD code and then immediately launch the call from the telephone's native call manager.
My problem is the difficulty in achieving this goal. Basically, I cannot initiate the call immediately after the USSD code has run.

A base project is generated with **expo**, but I realized that the following three libraries cannot work on expo, which led me to eject my project with the command **expo eject** ( https: //docs.expo. io / expokit / eject /)

I use the following libraries:

- **react-native-send-intention** (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-send-intent)

**typeError: RNSenddIntentAndroid.sendOhoneCall is not a function.(In 'RNSendIntentAndroid.sendPhoneCall(phoneNumber,phoneAphoneOnly)','RNSendIntentAndroid.sendPhoneCall' is undefined)**

- **native reactive phone call** (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-immediate-phone-call)

**typeError: null is not an an object(evaluating'_reactNative.NativeModule.RNImmediatePhoneCall.immediatePhoneCall')**

- **react-native-ussd-dial** (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ussd-dial)

**typeError: null is not an an object(evaluating'_reactNative.NativeModules.Device.DialNumber')**

With the three libraries above, I have the same error  [enter image description here][2]

- **Liaison** (https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking)

The problem with this library is that it does not immediately launch the USSD code and does not take the **#** character as a parameter

here is the code of my different pages

- **setting gradle**

```js
include ':react-native-ussd-dial'
project(':react-native-ussd-dial').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-ussd-dial/android')

include ':react-native-immediate-phone-call', ':app'
project(':react-native-immediate-phone-call').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-immediate-phone-call/android')

include ':RNSendIntentModule', ':app'
project(':RNSendIntentModule').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-send-intent/android')
```

- **build grandle**

```js
dependencies {
  implementation project(':react-native-send-intent')
  implementation project(':react-native-ussd-dial')
  implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
  implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+" // From node_modules
  addUnimodulesDependencies()

  if (enableHermes) {
    def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
    debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
    releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
  } else {
    implementation jscFlavor
  }

// here
  implementation project(':react-native-immediate-phone-call')
  compile project(':react-native-ussd-dial')
  compile project(':RNSendIntentModule')
}
```

-MainApplication.jaava

```js
@Override
protected List < ReactPackage > getPackages() {
  List < ReactPackage > packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
  packages.add(
    new ModuleRegistryAdapter(mModuleRegistryProvider),
    new RNSendIntentPackage(),
    new RNUssdDialPackage(),
    new RNImmediatePhoneCallPackage());
//here
  new RNImmediatePhoneCallPackage();
  new RNUssdDialPackage();
  new RNSendIntentPackage();
  return packages;

}
```

- AndridManifeste.xml

```js
< uses - permission android: name = "android.permission.CALL_PHONE" / >
```

Comment: _"Messages typed completely in capital letters are often equated on social media to shouting and other impolite or argumentative behaviors."_ ([All caps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps))

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You are supposed to ask specific questions about problems with code you have written here - not just point to a couple of external libraries, and then vaguely mention that there was some sort of “error”.